# Preventing a specific application from relaunching at startup?

Tags: applications, startup

When I reboot my mac, I have the "Reopen windows when logging back in" option checked, and for most applications it works fine. However, there's a few applications I use that behave very badly at startup when this option is used. (They reopen on the wrong desktop, throw tons of windows in wrong places, display error messages, things like that.)

I'd like to stop those apps from relaunching at startup, but only those apps. I'd prefer to keep using the "Reopen windows when logging back in" option so that all my other applications reopen in their previous state. Is there any way I can do that?

edit: A few points of clarification:

1. None of these apps are specified as login items.
2. Quitting the apps before rebooting doesn't actually seem to work. It may be the case that apps have to be closed for a sufficient length of time (and I don't know what that duration is) before they will no longer be relaunched at next login. I believe it's the same issue as reported here: [How can I prevent applications from re-launching at startup?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/75902/how-can-i-prevent-applications-from-re-launching-at-startup)

Comment: It's actually only a matter of seconds wait for them to not register at reboot, so long as you quit the apps before springing the 'Reopen...' dialog. Once that's open, it would seem the list is already built.

Answer (score 1):

The best option would be to quit those specific applications before logging out.

Make sure you are quitting the program completely, and not just closing the windows.

Edit: As an alternative, you can disable Reopen Windows When Logging Back In and add the programs you would like to open to the Login Items.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't seem to work for a few reasons: 1) sometimes my system crashes and I have to do an emergency reboot, which doesn't allow me to quit apps ahead of time, 2) I often forget, and...

Comment: 3) it often doesn't work anyway! It might be necessary to quit the apps several minutes before the system shuts down. Apparently someone else has the same problem that I do, but asked about it six years ago: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/75902/how-can-i-prevent-applications-from-re-launching-at-startup

Comment: Hmm. I think the next best option would be to disable Reopen on Login and add the programs you want to open to the Login Items. I don't think there is a way to exempt programs from the Reopen on Login.

Comment: I posted my comment on your question before i read *these* comments... which turns it into an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info). Fix what's crashing the system, rather than try to band-aid the restart process.

Comment: Well, I *would* fix the crashes, but a lot of the crashes are self inflicted because of the work I do. Basically my normal work flow often (though not always) involves reboots at unexpected times, and there's not much I can do about it, hence me asking about this.

Comment: @Christian Your idea of not using "reopen windows" and just setting the apps I want to open at login is actually a pretty good idea. Not sure why it didn't occur to me! You should post it as an answer to this thread since I may end up marking it as the solution.

Comment: @GuyGizmo I added to my answer to include both options.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to stop some certain softwares launching at startup automatically? If so, follow these steps.

`System Preferences > Users & Groups > Select your User ID (Left Side) > Login Items.`

There is a list of applications which opens automatically at startup. So you can either hide those applications yet allowing to launch at startup or you can remove them using Minus Button.

Comment: These applications are not specified as login items. They are being relaunched as a result of "Reopen windows when logging back in".